# Javascript says "Function not defined", but it is defined on my simple web page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple web page for a buddy of mine to test out and win a free dilly bar from dairy queen (and teach me more about javascript at the same time). Unfortunately, Javascript claims that my function is undefined, but as you can see from the code, it is defined. Not sure what is happening here, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

I first made a simple page that had 3 textboxes: Paycheck Amount, IOU's, and Net Pay, and you clicked a button and it subtracted IOU's from the Paycheck Amount, and displayed the result in the Net Pay box. It worked fine, so I modified the code to make the free Dilly Bar page, and for some reason it doesn't work now. I have some previous programming experience, but I'll confess I'm lost now. I read that it's bad practice to use OnClick, but in the previous page OnClick did the trick just fine, so not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```js
    document.write("Fill in the boxes then click the button!");

    function dbCode() {
 
 if document.getElementById("firstNum").value == "5" && 
    document.getElementById("secondNum").value == "50" {
 
   alert("Congratluations! Your code is: 12345678");
   
    }
 
    }
```

```html
    What is the next number in the pattern?<BR><BR>
    1,2,3,4?<input type = "text" id = "firstNum"><BR><BR>
    10,20,30,40?:<input type = "text" id = "secondNum"><BR><BR>

    <input type = "button" OnClick = "dbCode();" value = "Get your Dilly Bar 
    Code!"><BR><BR>
```

I was expecting the output to be 12345678 in the form of an alert box...instead, nothing happens.

Comment: Check your browser console for the syntax error message.

Comment: The problem is if parentheses are missing in your if statement

Comment: You're also missing `()` for the condition, after your if statement.

Comment: @Hadnazzar the function is supposed to be called by clicking the <button>

Comment: @Kris  When the browser tells you that a "function is undefined" what it really means is "that function is not _correctly_ defined" - either its in the wrong place, or in this case there is a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just miss to wrap the if conditions with ().

```js
    document.write("Fill in the boxes then click the button!");

    function dbCode() {
 
 if (document.getElementById("firstNum").value == "5" && 
    document.getElementById("secondNum").value == "50") {
 
   alert("Congratluations! Your code is: 12345678");
   
    }
 
    }
```

```html
    What is the next number in the pattern?<BR><BR>
    1,2,3,4?<input type = "text" id = "firstNum"><BR><BR>
    10,20,30,40?:<input type = "text" id = "secondNum"><BR><BR>

    <input type = "button" OnClick = "dbCode();" value = "Get your Dilly Bar 
    Code!"><BR><BR>
```

Comment: Thanks so much everyone! Gonna go try it now! I can't believe I overlooked something so small, lol!

Comment: Ok, it works like a charm now! Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

You've just made a minor error with your `if` statement - you've missed off the brackets around the criteria:

```
if (document.getElementById("firstNum").value == "5" && 
    document.getElementById("secondNum").value == "50") {
```

Here's the working snippet:

```js
document.write("Fill in the boxes then click the button!");

function dbCode() {
    if (document.getElementById("firstNum").value == "5" && 
        document.getElementById("secondNum").value == "50") {
 
     alert("Congratluations! Your code is: 12345678");
   
    }
 
}
```

```html
   What is the next number in the pattern?<BR><BR>
   1,2,3,4?<input type = "text" id = "firstNum"><BR><BR>
   10,20,30,40?:<input type = "text" id = "secondNum"><BR><BR>

   <input type = "button" OnClick = "dbCode();" value = "Get your Dilly Bar 
   Code!"><BR><BR>
```

Comment: @Lewis: HTML attribute names are case-insensitive.